# error while adding data in ManyToManyField model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Here assignment Model has ManyToManyField with Tags but when I try to insert data using serializers I got an empty list [], in tags fields

here is my serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from assignment.models import (
    Assignment,
    Tag,
)
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for tags."""

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ["name"]


class AssignmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Assignment."""
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = Assignment
        fields = ["id", "name", "tags", "last_updated_by", "assignment_data"]
        read_only_fields = ["id"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create an Assignment."""
        tags_data = validated_data.pop("tags", [])
        instance = Assignment.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for tag_name in tags_data:
            created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
            instance.tags.set(tags)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

I am sending this value:

```
{
    "name": "demo assignment",
    "tags": ["demo"],
    "last_updated_by": "user1",
    "assignment_data":  {
                "hello": "Hello world 2"
            }
}
```

error:

```
  File "D:\Assignments-Api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 313, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

***Update***

Here is my models.py :

```
from django.db import models


class Tag(models.Model):
    """Tag for filtering Assignments."""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Assignment(models.Model):
    """Models for assigment"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    assignment_data = models.JSONField(blank=True)
    last_updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

please let me know if you require any other information like views.py , settings.py or any other files

Comment: Please share the models (`Assignment` and `Tag`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please check it added models.py